# Testing complex datatypes?

Tags: python, image, testing, opencv

What's are some ways of testing complex data types such as video, images, music, etc. I'm using TDD and wonder are there alternatives to "gold file" testing for rendering algorithms. I understand that there's ways to test other parts of the program that don't render and using those results you can infer. However, I'm particularly interested in rendering algorithms specifically image/video testing.

The question came up while I was using OpenCV/Python to do some basic facial recognition and want to verify its correctness.

Even if there's nothing definitive any suggestion will help.

Comment: I guess you're taking TDD too far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea how to test rendering is quite simple: to test a function use the [inverse function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_function) and check if the input and output match (match is not equality in your case):

```
f(f^-1(x)) = x
```

To test a rendering algorithm you would encode the raw input, render the encoded values and analyze the difference between the rendered output and the raw input. One problem is to get the raw input, when encoding/decoding random input is not appropriate. Another challenge is to evaluate the differences between the raw input and rendering output. I suppose if you're writing some rendering software you should be able to do a frequency analysis on the data. (Some [transformation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_transform) should pop into your head now.)

If it is possible generate your test data. Text fixtures are a real maintenance problem. They only shine in the beginning. If they are changing in some kind everything breaks down. The main problem is that if your using a fixture your tests are going to repeat the fixture's content. This makes the interpretation of intent of your tests harder. If there is a magic value in your test what's the significant part of this value?

Fixture:

```
actual = parse("file.xml")
expected = "magic value"
assert(actual == expected)
```

Generated values:

```
expected = generate()
input = render(expected)
actual = parse()
assert(actual == expected)
```

The nice thing with [generators](http://theyougen.blogspot.com/2009/07/generators.html) is that you can build quite complex object graphs with them starting from primitive types and fields ([python Quickcheck version](http://dan.bravender.us/2009/6/21/Simple_Quickcheck_implementation_for_Python.html)).

Generator based tests are not deterministic by nature. But given enough trials they follow the [Law of large numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_large_numbers).

Their additional value is that they will produce a good test **value range** coverage. (Which is hard to achieve with test fixtures.) They will find unanticipated bugs in your code.

An alternative test approach is to test with a equivalent function:

```
f(x) = f'(x)
```

For example if you have a rendering function to compare against. This kind of test approach is useful if you have a working function. This function is your benchmark. It cannot be used in production because it is to slow or does use to much memory but can be easily debugged or proven to be correct.

Comment: Wow thanks a lot! This was the answer I was expecting, I'm not too concerned with TDD but the maintenance issues presented with gold files.

Comment: @dasickis - I added an alternative approach. That could be useful and easier to implement.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks a lot, I'll report back after I talk to my professor. They'll be teaching an entire class about unit testing so I'm doing some research for that.

Comment: Really, unit testing is taught in college courses (university? I'm confused by the American education system)? Could you provide some material?

Comment: Well it's "unit testing -- random testing -- theorem proving course", it's a theoretical approach to testing programs. Versus here's how you a test a method that does X. I'll post material with permission from the professor.

Comment: I'm at Northeastern University, there's a heavy focus on writing short, simple, and testable code. Also, the code must be maintainable, readable, and extensible. There's a bias towards "bottom-up approach" and every line of code must be tested. The tests don't need to be exhuastive but they shouldn't be trivial either. For more info: http://www.plt-scheme.org/ or http://www.ccs.neu.edu/home/matthias/ and browse through his links.

Answer (score 0):

What's wrong with the "gold file" technique?  It's part of your test fixture.  Every test has a data fixture that's the equivalent to the "gold file" in a media-intensive application.

When doing ordinary TDD of ordinary business applications, one often has a golden database fixture that must be used.

Even when testing simple functions and core classes of an application, the `setUp` method creates a kind of "gold file" fixture for that class or function.

What's wrong with that technique?  Please update your question with the specific problems you're having.